# Mouse and Audio Issues

Tags: audio, mouse, troubleshooting, help

I am new to computer building as I built my first one about a year ago. The computer ran fine for most of the time but recently the mouse skips around on the screen (kind of like the mouse is lagging) and the audio cuts out or sounds robotic. I checked the driver's and all drivers are up to date. All temperatures are good. The system is not overheating or over utilized. The mouse will skip on just the desktop and the audio acts up in discord calls. I'm not sure where to look at what the problem is any help would be appreciated.

Components are:

Motherboard:MSI Pro Z690-A

CPU:Intel I7 12700k

GPU:GEFORCE RTX 3070

CPU Cooler:Deepcool AG400

Power Supply:Corsair RM750x

Ram:Corsair 16GBx2 5600MHz

Ssd:Western Digital 2TB

And OS is Win 11

Thanks in advance